# usage of "here we go"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> in many context the expression "here we go" is used, in a soccer match, in TV Shows by Show men , in some songs for example:
>   Oh, here we go
>   Feel it in my soul

I'd like to know what does it mean exactly?

Comment: In a soccer match, it's an expression of solidarity with other fans that usually indicates optimism about the outcome of the match, but has no specific meaning. The phrase "songs and so on" is too vague to be meaningful in the context of a question.

Comment: In the context of the song lyric you posted, "here we go" seems to mean that something has just begun to happen. For example, if the singer has just fallen in love, he or she could say, "Oh, here we go / Feel it in my soul." The meaning would essentially be, "Oh, love is here/love has begun / Feel it in my soul."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Here we go!

This phrase represents an event that is about to begin:

> You are about to start a presentation and you say, "Here we go!"

However it can also be used negatively or sarcastically:

> Your Mom enters your room and starts to scold you and you say, "oh, here we go!"

In the case of the song lyrics you have posted, the phrase "Here we go" mean that something positive is about to begin.